# C/C++ Error E2268 : Call to undefined function 'fread' in function retornaClientes()

Tags: c

Olá,

Estou fazendo um projeto para faculdade, em C/C++ (mais linguagem C do que C++), e estou com um problema sério na função fread().

```
DataManipulation.h | 88 | Error E2285: Could not find a match for 'fread(_CLIENTE,unsigned int,int,FILE *)' in function retornaClientes()

DataManipulation.h | 88 | Error E2268: Call to undefined function 'fread' in function retornaClientes()|
```

Soluções que me propuseram já:
- Verificar se o nome da função e os parâmetros estão corretos;
- Verificar se está sendo importada a biblioteca correspondente, no caso é a stdio.h;

Obtive esse mesmo erro com outras funções de bibliotecas que eu mesmo criei, mas sempre resolvi no modo "gambiarra", fugindo a solução de verdade, só que agora eu tenho o problema em uma função de uma biblioteca nativa, e não tenho como fazer uma "gambiarra", então preciso solucionar esse problema com a função, e claro, aplicá-lo a todas as funções que também estão "bugadas" mas funcionando na base da gambiarra.

A gambiarra que eu digo, é copiar a função (implementação dela) e criar uma identica dentro da mesma biblioteca que está dando o problema, mas ai que está, a fread() pertence à stdio.h, e eu não tenho como "dar esse jeitinho".

Linha de código em que uso fread():

```
fread(recebeRegistro, sizeof(_CLIENTE), 1, base_cliente); //lê o registro
```

Linha importando as bibliotecas:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Eu utilizo IDE Code::Blocks e o compilador Borland 5.5

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido pessoal.

Falta de atenção imensa minha, o meu problema era o seguinte:
- A função fread() recebe no primeiro parâmetro o LOCAL onde a o conteúdo do arquivo binário lido será armazenado, acontece que, eu preciso passar o PONTEIRO para o local da memória onde será armazenado, e eu, desatento, tentei passar o CONTEÚDO da variável "recebeRegistro".

Ou seja, erro bobo de implementação meu.

Att.